# python - binary encoding of column containing multiple terms

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do a binary transformation of a column containing lists of strings separated by `comma`.

Can you help me in getting from here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id': [1,2,3],
                   'test': [['one', 'two', 'three'], 
                            ['three', 'one'], 
                            ['four', 'one']]})
df

_id  test
 1   [one, two, three]
 2   [three, one]
 3   [four, one]
```

to:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'_id': [1,2,3], 
                          'one': [1,1,1], 
                          'two': [1,0,0], 
                          'three': [1,1,0], 
                          'four': [0,0,1]})

df_result[['_id', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]

 _id    one two  three  four
   1    1   1    1      0
   2    1   0    1      0
   3    1   0    0      1
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column out, convert to `str` by [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('test').str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
print (df)
   _id  four  one  three  two
0    1     0    1      1    1
1    2     0    1      1    0
2    3     1    1      0    0
```

Instead `pop` is possible use `drop`:

```
df = df.drop('test', axis=1).join(df.pop('test').str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
print (df)
   _id  four  one  three  two
0    1     0    1      1    1
1    2     0    1      1    0
2    3     1    1      0    0
```

Solution with new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('test').values.tolist()), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
df = df.join(df1.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max())
print (df)
   _id  four  one  three  two
0    1     0    1      1    1
1    2     0    1      1    0
2    3     1    1      0    0
```

I try also solution with converting to `string` by `astype`, but some cleaning is necessary:

```
df1=df.pop('test').astype(str).str.strip("'[]").str.replace("',\s+'", '|').str.get_dummies()
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   _id  four  one  three  two
0    1     0    1      1    1
1    2     0    1      1    0
2    3     1    1      0    0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) method:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('test')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=df.index))
```

Result:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   _id  four  one  three  two
0    1     0    1      1    1
1    2     0    1      1    0
2    3     1    1      0    0
```